# slow python script when looping through a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv

I am splitting a csv into two csvs, based on a value in a column in the original csv. This code works, but takes about an hour to run on a csv with about 10000 records. I have tried enumerating the list, but I don't think that was the correct approach to speeding this up.

I am extremely slow and very new to this programming and would appreciate if someone would be able to explain where to focus my next efforts to make this faster. I know the least number of lines is best, but I don't understand how to loop through when creating two separate csvs. Is the loop even the issue here?

```
myList = ['2','12','20','33'...]
with open(originalCSV, 'rb') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
   rows = [row for row in reader if row['Column 10'] in myList]
for row in rows:
   with open(inmylistCSV, 'wb') as w:
       fieldnames = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 5', 'Column 10']
       csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=fieldnames)
       csvwriter.writeheader()
       csvwriter.writerows(rows)

with open(originalCSV, 'rb') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
   rows = [row for row in reader if row['Column 10'] not in myList]
for row in rows:
   with open(notinmylistCSV, 'wb') as w:
       fieldnames = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 5', 'Column 10']
       csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=fieldnames)
       csvwriter.writeheader()
       csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are repeating the loop for the 10,000 records twice, resulting in doing twice the amount of work, which is 20,000 records.

```
# This is what your doing

for x in range(10000):
    if is_odd(x):
       print('I am odd')

for x in range(10000):
    if is_even(x):
       print('I am even')
```

A simple fix would be simply to combine your logic into this

```
# This is what you should be doing

for x in range(10000):
    if is_odd(x):
       print('I am odd')
    else:
       print('I am even')
```

So, in conclusion, you have 2 things you should do right now

1. combine the following lines logically

```
rows = [row for row in reader if row['Column 10'] in myList]
rows = [row for row in reader if row['Column 10'] not in myList]
```

2. optimize the csv writing portion of code

```
with open(notinmylistCSV | inmylistCSV, 'wb') as w:
   fieldnames = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 5', 'Column 10']
   csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=fieldnames)
   csvwriter.writeheader()
   csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

why not just read through the original CSV and distribute the rows to the other CSVs?

```
myList = ['2','12','20','33'...]

fieldnames = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 5', 'Column 10']

in_list = open(inmylistCSV, 'wb')
in_list_csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(in_list, fieldnames=fieldnames)
in_list_csvwriter.writeheader()

not_in_list = with open(notinmylistCSV, 'wb')
not_in_list_csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(not_in_list, fieldnames=fieldnames)
not_in_list_csvwriter.writeheader()

with open(originalCSV, 'rb') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
   for row in reader:
       if row['Column 10'] in myList:
           in_list_csvwriter.writerow(row)
       else:
           not_in_list_csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tired this too and it also worked perfectly. Much appreciated